# Error al procesar el pago de la API de Mercado Pago

Tags: php, html

Estoy elaborando una tienda virtual como proyecto, al realizar el pago por mercado pago, el precio de pago es correcto. Pero al momento de procesar el pago me marca una leyenda la cual es: **Oh no,algo anduvo mal**.

Entrando herramientas de administradores siempre que se carga la pantalla me marca este mensaje:

`[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.mercadolibre.com".`

Siendo el código que uso el siguiente:

````
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('MyAccess_Token');

$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->id = '001';
$item->title = 'Producto X';
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = 150.00;
$item->currency_id = "MXN";

$preference->items = array($item);
$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "http://localhost:8080/pagina%20web%20zapateria%20cristopher/Pagina%20Web/captura.php",
    "failure" => "http://localhost:8080/pagina%20web%20zapateria%20cristopher/Pagina%20Web/fallo.php"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";
$preference->binary_mode = true;
$preference->save();


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Mercado Pago</h3>
    <div class="checkout-btn"></div>

    <script>
        const mp= new MercadoPago('TEST-39013560-af42-4173-a793-6b9b7010b39d',{
            locale: 'es-MX'
        });
        mp.checkout({
            preference:{
                id:'<?php echo $preference->id; ?>'
            },
            render:{
                container:'.checkout-btn',
                label: 'Pagar con MP'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html> ```
````